# Issue with WPF validation(IDataErrorInfo) and tab focusing

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, tabcontrol, idataerrorinfo

I have a `TextBox` bound to a property of an object which implements `IDataErrorInfo`. 
I set up the `Validation.ErrorTemplate` of the `TextBox`, and it works fine. The problem is that I have these on a `TabControl`, and the validation template doesn't display any more if I change the tab to another one and then come back to the initial tab (where the `TextBox` is). It looks like it is validated(like the value is correct), but actually it is not.

This is the `IDataErrorInfo` object - note that a "correct" value is a string with a length of 2:

```
public class Presenter : IDataErrorInfo
{
    public Presenter()
    {
        this.Property = String.Empty;
    }

    public string Property { get; set; }

    public string Error { get { return null; } }

    public string this[string columnName]
    {
        get
        {
             if (columnName == "Property")
             {
                if (this.Property.Length == 2)
                   return null;
                else
                   return "Invalid property length!";
             }
             else return null;
        }
    }
}
```

and this is the XAML:

```
<TabControl >
    <TabItem Header="tabItem1" Name="tabItem1" GotFocus="tabItem1_GotFocus">
        <Grid>
            <TextBox Width="100" Height="20" x:Name="txtField">
                <TextBox.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                        <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate">
                            <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate>
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="16"/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <AdornedElementPlaceholder Grid.Column="0"/>
                                    <Image Source="bullets16.png" Grid.Column="1" ToolTip="{Binding CurrentItem.ErrorContent, Mode=OneWay}">
                                    </Image>
                                </Grid>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </TextBox.Style>
                <TextBox.Text>
                    <Binding Path="Property" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" ValidatesOnDataErrors="True">
                    </Binding>
                </TextBox.Text>
            </TextBox>
        </Grid>
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem Header="tabItem2" Name="tabItem2" >
        <Grid />
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Tab items tend to mess up with adorners (although I don't know why, I experienced it).

I could reproduce your problem.

Solve it by wrapping the contents of the TabItem with an AdornerDecorator.

So:

```
<TabControl >
    <TabItem Header="tabItem1" Name="tabItem1" GotFocus="tabItem1_GotFocus">

        <AdornerDecorator>

           <Grid>
           ....
           </Grid>

        </AdornerDecorator>

    </TabItem>
    ...
</TabControl>
```

Comment: This is also a problem with the content of `Expander`, and the same solution applies.

Comment: A related blog post - [WPF Validation Errors Disappear Inside TabControl When Switching TabItems](http://karlshifflett.wordpress.com/2008/02/19/wpf-validation-errors-disappear-inside-tabcontrol-when-switching-tabitems/)

Comment: Not a complete solution. Initial validation only works for the first selected tab item, the rest of them won't validate automatically when you later switch into them. I found out that by manually setting the DataContext in code behind in them at OnLoad solves this issue as well but it's ugly. I'm still searching for a solution...

Comment: Ran into this using while targeting .NET 4.5.2 and using `INotifyDataErrorInfo` instead of `IDataErrorInfo` and this solution worked great for my use case.

Comment: The link from @akjoshi is dead. Here's an archive of it: https://web.archive.org/web/20150627034202/https://karlshifflett.wordpress.com/2008/02/19/wpf-validation-errors-disappear-inside-tabcontrol-when-switching-tabitems/

Answer (score 1):

I had problem with only first (focused) tab got style and only that one persisted after changing. This is solution I ended up with (without `AdornerDecorator`)

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type FrameworkElement}" x:Key="ValidatingControl">
<Style.Triggers>
    <MultiTrigger>
        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            <Condition Property="Validation.HasError" Value="True" />
            <Condition Property="IsVisible" Value="True" />
        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
        <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
                        <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1">
                            <AdornedElementPlaceholder Name="controlWithError"/>
                        </Border>
                    </DockPanel>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="ToolTip" 
        Value="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self}, Path=(Validation.Errors).CurrentItem.ErrorContent}" />
    </MultiTrigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

Based on this article: <del>http://techqa.info/programming/question/1369643/wpf-error-styles-only-being-rendered-properly-on-visible-tab-of-a-tab-control</del> (No longer exists)

Comment: Bad link, goes to a pay site.

Comment: It wasn't at the time. Edited.