# WPF TextBox with validation loses ErrorTemplate

Tags: wpf, validation, textbox, tabcontrol, adornerdecorator

I have an issue very similar to these:

[Issue with WPF validation(IDataErrorInfo) and tab focusing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2355661/issue-with-wpf-validationidataerrorinfo-and-tab-focusing)

[TextBox with validation loses ErrorTemplate on tab change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9907075/textbox-with-validation-loses-errortemplate-on-tab-change)

`AdornerDecorator` do the trick **within the same instance** of the `Window`, but when the `Window` is reloaded and I switch to the `TabItem` containing the `TextBox` in error, the `ErrorTemplate` *won't show up anymore*.

```xml
<Window x:Class="Views.MyWindowView">
    <Grid>

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <TabControl HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                    Height="Auto"
                    VerticalAlignment="Top"
                    Width="Auto"
                    SelectionChanged="TabItemChanged"
                    Name="MyTabControl">

            <!-- Below, AdornerDecorator are added for the following reason:
                 the Validation.Error cues are painted in the Adorner Layer. 
                 When tabs are switched, that layer is discarded. -->

            <!-- The view 1 tab.-->
            <TabItem Header="{Resx tab1_Header}"
                     Name="Tbi1">
                <AdornerDecorator>
                    <vw:MyView1 DataContext="{Binding}"/>
                </AdornerDecorator>
            </TabItem>

            <!-- The view 2 tab.-->
            <TabItem Header="{Resx tab2_Header}"
                     Name="Tbi2">
                <AdornerDecorator>
                    <vw:MyView2 DataContext="{Binding}"/>
                </AdornerDecorator>
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>
```

...

I tried to retrigger the validation in the code-behind on `TabControl` `SelectionChanged`, didn't work.

Any idea?

Comment: "When the window is reloaded"?  What does that mean?  Why is your window reloading?  How is it reloading?

Comment: That's a modal dialog window. It can get opened and closed many times. That's what I mean by "reloading".

Comment: Are you hiding it and showing it, rather than destroying it inbetween?

Comment: It is a new instance each time; i.e., it is destroyed. Note that when I switch tabs in the xaml, ErrorTemplate do show up on the TextBox at runtime. It is only when I have to navigate to the TabItem that it won't work.

Comment: Is it just that it's not checking your IDataErrorInfo properties on initial load?  You can set some breakpoints to check on that.  If not, you *could* force INPC events on all your properties after load... It's in no way optimal, but it could get you past this.

Comment: The IDataErrorInfo properties are checked. Actually, and oddly enough, wrapping the TextBox within an AdornerDecorator as suggested by @Funk below did the trick.

Comment: Good on you!  These kinds of issues are a PITA to track and fix.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Putting together the pieces of the puzzle**

An [AdornerLayer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.adornerlayer(v=vs.110).aspx) represents a surface for rendering adorners. 
As an `AdornerLayer` usually serves an entire view, not just one control, some containers implement them by default.

An [adorner](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743737(v=vs.110).aspx) is a custom `FrameworkElement` that is bound to a `UIElement`. Adorners are rendered in an `AdornerLayer`, which is a rendering surface that is always on top of the adorned element or a collection of adorned elements.

So in this case the adorner (red rectangle) is bound to a `TextBox`, but is rendered in a layer on top of the `TextBox`.

Adorning (e.g. in case of a validation error) is done by calling the static method `GetAdornerLayer` to get an `AdornerLayer` object for the `UIElement` to be adorned.

**Enough theory**

Changing `TabItems` discards the `AdornerLayer`, resulting in the adorner not being drawn. 2 fixes:

\The manual way, as proposed by DRapp:

```
<XAML for MyView1>
   <AdornerDecorator>
      ...
   </AdornerDecorator>
</close XAML for MyView1>
```

Of course, if there's another container implementing an `AdornerLayer` between the `AdornerDecorator` and the `TextBox` (in the visual tree), this won't do any good. So the explicit `AdornerDecorator` needs to be the last one wrapping the `TextBox`.

```
<XAML for MyView1>
    <Grid>

        ...

        <GroupBox>
            <AdornerDecorator>
                <Grid>

                    ...

                    <TextBox ... />
                </Grid>
            </AdornerDecorator>
        </GroupBox>
    </Grid>
</close XAML for MyView1>
```

\Second solution (which I prefer) resetting the [ErrorTemplate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.validation.errortemplate(v=vs.110).aspx) each time the `TextBox` becomes visible. In doing so the lack of `AdornerLayer` gets spotted and fixed.

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsVisible" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate>
                            <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1">
                                <AdornedElementPlaceholder/>
                            </Border>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Answer (score 2):

I have seen some strange things with WPF and would offer this suggestion.  Per the other posts you referenced and tried to apply here with wrapping your view with the adorner decorator,  move the wrapping of the adorner directly into your "MvView1" XAML page.

From your existing...

```
<AdornerDecorator>
   <vw:MyView1 DataContext="{Binding}"/>
</AdornerDecorator>
```

change to...

```
<vw:MyView1 DataContext="{Binding}"/>
```

and in

```
<XAML for MyView1>
   <AdornerDecorator>
      [wrapping is within the view... then the rest of the view...]
   </AdornerDecorator>
</close XAML for MyView1>
```

I have noticed similar such as applying visibility of controls that unless some things are at one level they work, at another they don't.  Never found the exact pattern though.

Comment: @CTZStef Some controls (e.g. [Groupbox](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33911629/4838058)) seem to break the flow and require the `AdornerDecorator` to be placed within. As a quick check, try wrapping the `TextBox`.

Comment: @Funk wrapping the TextBox within an AdornerDecorator works; please create an answer and I will gladly accept it. If you could also add a few details about this magic, that would be great. Thanks!